# Child grid overflows parent grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I have a flexbox-container width a fixed height and 3 children. One of them has a `display: grid` and a grid-item with an aspect-ratio. I don't understand why the grid items doesn't expand the grid's width so that the parent flex container also can grow its width. Somehow the aspect-ratio is the problem but I don't get it.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex-child {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

.grid-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  gap: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.grid_item {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.player {
  min-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
    <div class="grid-child">
      <div class="grid_item player"></div>
      <div class="grid_item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Markus-Rappat/pen/XWobKrL?editors=1100)